# Вычисление по формуле используя показания разных датчиков, которые считываются в разные моменты времени

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Допустим, имеется три показания датчиков A, B, C. Эти параметры считываются периодически отдельной службой, которая передает их по AMQP. Я пишу службу(.net core 2.1), которая будет подписана на получение этих данных по AMQP. С датчиков данные считываются каждые 2 секунды, но с разбросом в 200-500мс. Т.е. Мне в программу по AMQP асинхронно приходит три сообщения:

```
{Param: A; Value: 2; Date: 06.04.2021 10:00:00.100},
{Param: B; Value: 3; Date: 06.04.2021 10:00:00.300},
{Param: C; Value: -3; Date: 06.04.2021 10:00:00.254}
```

затем через 2 секунды приходит аналогичный набор, но с другими значениями и датами (+2 сек)
Мне нужно собрать параметры A,B,C и применить к ним некую формулу, для получения результирующего значения, пусть будет A+B+C. Сложность для меня состоит в том, что A,B и С приходят асинхронно разными сообщениями.
Выходит, при получении одного из параметров, который пришел первым, мне нужно вызывать метод вычисления по формуле и блокировать его до тех пор пока не будут получены остальные два параметра. Затем через 2 сек процедура повторяется. (Или что-то в этом роде)

С помощью каких инструментов можно реализовать такой механизм? Mutex? DataFlow?

Comment: А почему просто не копить значения в списке и как наберутся все три не инициировать расчёт? Сообщения могут приходить с задержкой и т.д. или ровно по три приходят и по времени их не нужно группировать? Если группировать не нужно то вообще не вижу проблемы. Если нужно, то я бы в какой `ConcurrentDictionary` собирал с ключём - округлённым временем сборки. Ну или что-то типа того.

Comment: Сообщения приходят в идеале с задержкой в 200-500мс в среднем. Вообще, набор параметров не ограничивается только тремя. Их может быть и 10 и 50. И разное кол-во формул. Например, могут приходить параметры A,B,C,X,Y,Z и вычисление происходить по формулам A+B+C и X*Y*Z. Т.е. 6 параметров будут считываться с датчиков и преобразовываться в 2 результирующих сигнала.

Comment: Просто я это видел примерно в таком ключе:
Формула оборачивается в Action. Action запаковывается в объект, который создается каждый раз при получении одного из зависимых параметров. В этом объект происходит ожидание остальных зависимых параметров и затем выполнение Action'а.

Comment: Ну, я просто не понимаю, зачем ловить приходящие данные двумя разными способами, зачем всё так сложно. Почему не копить данные в одном месте и не инициировать расчёт когда все нужные данные собраны.

Comment: `.net core 2.1` - скоро будет снят с поддержки, устарел, используйте как минимум 3.1

Comment: Создавайте список для каждого датчика, заводите ограничитель для каждого датчика по кол-ву или по времени, при выходе за пределы условия времени/кол-ва удаляете самые старые пока условия не будут соблюдаться, данную операцию необходимо делать в одном потоке с получением данных AMQP сообщений, когда все лимиты удовлетворяют условиям - вызывать функцию с вычислением по вашим формулам. А если требуются дополнительные условия, например: между A, B, C не должно быть разницы более секунды - прям в функции и проверять, если слишком большая разница - пропускать итерацию. Результат складывать отдельно.

Comment: Спасибо, примерно понял в каком направлении двигаться!